# @RunWith(Suite.class) @Suite.SuiteClasses({ array })

Tags: java

I have an array list in another package, which looks like:

```
String [ ] classes= {"SuiteTest1", "SuiteTest2"}
```

How can I get those classes and set `@SuiteClasses({})`?

```
package guru99.junit;       
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;        
import org.junit.runners.Suite;     

@RunWith(Suite.class)               
@Suite.SuiteClasses({               
  SuiteTest1.class,
  SuiteTest2.class,             
})
```

Comment: i have an array list in another package, which looks like: String [ ] classes= {"SuiteTest1", "SuiteTest2"}

Answer (score 2):

It is **NOT** possible to pass values from an array to `@SuiteClasses` or any other annotation for that matter. Values passed to any annotation must be a compile time constant.

If you have an array as

```
final String[] classes= {"SuiteTest1", "SuiteTest2"};
```

It can be modified with `classes[0] = "SuiteTest3"` and hence cannot always be trusted to be a constant.

Since an array is mutable, it is not accepted as a compile time constant and hence cannot be accepted by an annotation.

Comment: Hello Medhu, thank you for your answer. But I get the classes as Json from a website. Can I Write the classes in a csv file with Puffers help and use it in the  SuiteClasses?

Comment: @AhmedAldam even if you write the classes in a csv file, you would not be able to use it with `SuiteClasses` since even then it would not be a compile time constant.